# does jmeter let you run tests against a swagger API definition?

Tags: api, jmeter, swagger

does jmeter let you run tests against a swagger API definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of box - no, you need to define all the [HTTP Requests](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) either manually (or record them using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)). Alternative options are:

1. [Import your Swagger API definition into SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/extension-plugins/bundled.html) using [SoapUI Swagger Plugin](https://github.com/SmartBear/readyapi-swagger-plugin), once you have SoapUI requests you should be able to [convert SoapUI Test plan into JMeter .jmx script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-soapui-xml-jmeter-jmx)
2. Check out [swagger-codegen-jmeter](https://github.com/wilsonmar/oss-perf/tree/master/swagger-codegen-jmeter) tool